# Magento duplicate meta tags in google webmaster

Tags: url, seo

I have magento 1.7. 
For seo reasons I am getting Duplicate meta descriptions Tags problem from google.

For example

- /paralympics-paralympische-spelen/
- /paralympics-paralympische-spelen

(with and without the slash)

AND

- /blog/
- /blog/?p=2
- /blog/?p=3
- /blog/index/list/tag/oranje/

AND

- /troonswisseling
- /troonswisseling?dir=asc&limit=48&order=position

**How can we make only 1 page exist (instead of all these combinations)**

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First I would login to the Webmaster Tools with Google and you can specify parameters for it to ignore like you're experiencing with some URLs.  Site Configuration -> URL Parameters

I would also make sure you are submitting `sitemap.xml` properly to Google and other Search engines to help ensure things are crawled properly.

Robots.txt docs:

- https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt

Next I would make sure your robots.txt file is being read and recognized.  Here is one I've used with success before:

```
## robots.txt for Magento Community and Enterprise

## GENERAL SETTINGS

## Enable robots.txt rules for all crawlers
User-agent: *

## Crawl-delay parameter: number of seconds to wait between successive requests to the same server.
## Set a custom crawl rate if you're experiencing traffic problems with your server.
# Crawl-delay: 30

## Magento sitemap: uncomment and replace the URL to your Magento sitemap file
# Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap/sitemap.xml

## DEVELOPMENT RELATED SETTINGS

## Do not crawl development files and folders: CVS, svn directories and dump files
Disallow: CVS
Disallow: .svn
Disallow: .idea
Disallow: .sql
Disallow: .tgz

## GENERAL MAGENTO SETTINGS

## Do not crawl Magento admin page
Disallow: /admin/

## Do not crawl common Magento technical folders
Disallow: /app/
Disallow: /downloader/
Disallow: /errors/
Disallow: /includes/
Disallow: /lib/
Disallow: /pkginfo/
Disallow: /shell/
Disallow: /var/

## Do not crawl common Magento files
Disallow: /api.php
Disallow: /cron.php
Disallow: /cron.sh
Disallow: /error_log
Disallow: /get.php
Disallow: /install.php
Disallow: /LICENSE.html
Disallow: /LICENSE.txt
Disallow: /LICENSE_AFL.txt
Disallow: /README.txt
Disallow: /RELEASE_NOTES.txt

## MAGENTO SEO IMPROVEMENTS

## Do not crawl sub category pages that are sorted or filtered.
Disallow: /*?dir*
Disallow: /*?dir=desc
Disallow: /*?dir=asc
Disallow: /*?limit=all
Disallow: /*?mode*

## Do not crawl 2-nd home page copy (example.com/index.php/). Uncomment it only if you activated Magento SEO URLs.
## Disallow: /index.php/

## Do not crawl links with session IDs
Disallow: /*?SID=

## Do not crawl checkout and user account pages
Disallow: /checkout/
Disallow: /onestepcheckout/
Disallow: /customer/
Disallow: /customer/account/
Disallow: /customer/account/login/

## Do not crawl seach pages and not-SEO optimized catalog links
Disallow: /catalogsearch/
Disallow: /catalog/product_compare/
Disallow: /catalog/category/view/
Disallow: /catalog/product/view/

## SERVER SETTINGS

## Do not crawl common server technical folders and files
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /cleanup.php
Disallow: /apc.php
Disallow: /memcache.php
Disallow: /phpinfo.php

## IMAGE CRAWLERS SETTINGS

## Extra: Uncomment if you do not wish Google and Bing to index your images
# User-agent: Googlebot-Image
# Disallow: /
# User-agent: msnbot-media
# Disallow: /
```

Source: http://turnkeye.com/blog/optimize-robots-txt-for-magento/

Answer (score 6):

I believe you are looking for canonical links.

If you go to your admin panel and navigate to `system` -> `Configuration` -> `Catalog`

In the `Search Engine Optimisation` tab, you can find the following two entries:

- **Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Categories**
- **Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Products**

This will not delete the redundant pages, but will add the same canonical links in head of your html files, like so:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/paralympics-paralympische-spelen/"/>
```

That same link will be added for `/paralympics-paralympische-spelen/` and `/paralympics-paralympische-spelen`.

Now when google indexes your site, it will probably still see both links, but since you added a canonical link to it, google will now know that both links are the same page.

Comment: Strange thing is that both are already set to yes: Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Categories
 [STORE VIEW] 
Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Products
 [STORE VIEW]

Comment: And in addtion. I mus t admit that the pages above are all either CMS or BLOG pages (not product and category). The question is then how I would add canonical to also these pages. http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/adding_canonical_url_to_cms_pages

Answer (score 0):

I also add these to the robots.txt:

```
Disallow: /wishlist/
Disallow: /onepagecheckout/
Disallow: /review/
```

You don't want wishlists as that is user data. I use the onepagecheckout extension so I also exclude that. I choose to hide reviews because they create duplicate product titles out of the box and I haven't found a work-around for this yet.