# Help me understand how Google bots find product "id" links and how to block without negative impact

Tags: url, seo

I've been periodically checking Google Webmaster Tools and recently noticed a large number of ERROR 500 messages for links to pages that do not exist.

Example:

```
http://www.mysite.com/eng/catalog/product/view/id/21826/s/URL_KEY/ RESPONSE CODE 500
```

The ID and URL KEY is valid on their own and correctly identify the product. The product does exist and if I change the URL to:

```
http://www.mysite.com/eng/URL_KEY.html
```

the page opens. Using the ID in the backend also shows the correct product.

All links to product pages in the frontend are in this format: http://www.mysite.com/eng/URL_KEY.html
 there is no reference to any URL that is using /catalog/product/view/id/21826/s/URL_KEY/.

How are Google bots finding these links if there is no reference in the frontend?

Can I safely Disallow: /catalog/ in my robots.txt to avoid error message in Google Webmaster Tools without negatively impacting my site?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The quick easy solution is to setup your `robots.txt` to ignore the parent path:

```
## Do not crawl seach pages and not-SEO optimized catalog links
Disallow: /catalogsearch/
Disallow: /catalog/product_compare/
Disallow: /catalog/category/view/
Disallow: /catalog/product/view/
```

Snippet from:

- http://turnkeye.com/blog/optimize-robots-txt-for-magento/
- Alternate Stackexchange based entire robots.txt file also here: [Magento duplicate meta tags in google webmaster](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/2763/magento-duplicate-meta-tags-in-google-webmaster/2806#2806)

To answer your question as how, dissecting the controller referenced will help:

File: **app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php**

```
 /**
 * Product view action
 */
public function viewAction()
{
    // Get initial data from request
    $categoryId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('category', false);
    $productId  = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $specifyOptions = $this->getRequest()->getParam('options');

    // Prepare helper and params
    $viewHelper = Mage::helper('catalog/product_view');

    $params = new Varien_Object();
    $params->setCategoryId($categoryId);
    $params->setSpecifyOptions($specifyOptions);

    // Render page
    try {
        $viewHelper->prepareAndRender($productId, $this, $params);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() == $viewHelper->ERR_NO_PRODUCT_LOADED) {
            if (isset($_GET['store'])  && !$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
                $this->_redirect('');
            } elseif (!$this->getResponse()->isRedirect()) {
                $this->_forward('noRoute');
            }
        } else {
            Mage::logException($e);
            $this->_forward('noRoute');
        }
    }
}
```

`$specifyOptions` would be the value to follow during a request.

Most likely the URL is being found via a `sitemap.xml` link generated, the SEO Sitemap catalog Magento Core module itself has `/catalog/seo_sitemap/category/`, or such.

The /s/ in your URL could mean a possible alternative store view could be the culprit as well.

Not sure what version of Magento you are on. If you are running the latest version of Magento CE or EE I believe the latest release causes the Google sitemap `sitemap.xml` generation return the true controller path like yours and not the `url_key`.

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks for sharing! Do you happen to know why those urls end up in the sitemap?

Comment: `app/code/core/Mage/Sitemap/Model/Sitemap.php` should offer the most insight. http://svn.magentocommerce.com/source/branches/1.8/app/code/core/Mage/Sitemap/Model/Sitemap.php

Answer (score 3):

It's better to use a canonical tag for this, so whenever Google indexes `http://www.mysite.com/eng/catalog/product/view/id/21826/s/URL_KEY/`

it should have a canonical tag in the head like

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.mysite.com/eng/URL_KEY.html"/>
```

You can turn canonical tags on under `System > Configuration > Catalog > Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Products`

Comment: Hi Sander, this is already enabled. That is why I'm trying to find out how Goolge is finding these links and how to prevent them from being accessed. Thanks! SR